# What is the empty space in this document and how do I. get rid of them

Tags: whitespace, global-command

Here is my document:

[image]

What is the thing that my cursor is on? It is definitely not a whitspace as all white space should be marked with ␣.

And more importantly, how do I get rid of it?
I have tried

```
:g/^$/d
```

command to get rid of all blank lines but this doesn't work with these lines.

Comment: type `ga` to tell what character it is

Comment: That is the end-of-line marker. Use `:set nolist` to disable showing that

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/): in this case, having the actual text, we could tell what the character is. Use `ga` as pointed out to identify the character. It may, for example, be a non-breaking space. You could use instead `:global/^\s*$/delete` to delete any lines containing only space/tab, or use the pattern `^[[:space:]]*$` to include even more characters, or possibly `[[= =]]` for an equivalence class

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I'm not so sure: with `listchars+=eol:$` when the line has no text, my cursor appears on the `$`, not before.